# How to fix "AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'predict'"

Tags: python, numpy, classification, pickle

I have trained a classifier model and its working nicely in terms of giving prediction(boolian) in my local machine.

```
% movie data
%            [Rating, Production_Budget_million] 
movie_data=[1,20]

likelihood_pos=multivariate_normal_pos.pdf(movie_data)
likelihood_neg=multivariate_normal_neg.pdf(movie_data)
post_pos=likelihood_pos*prior_pos/(likelihood_pos*prior_pos+likelihood_neg*prior_neg)
post_neg=likelihood_neg*prior_neg/(likelihood_neg*prior_neg+likelihood_pos*prior_pos)

pred= post_pos>post_neg
pred
```

[image: Predicting output as expected]

The problem I am facing ,after dumping the model as pickle when  I am trying to calling the model and test with user data its giving an error"AttributeError: 'numpy.bool_' object has no attribute 'predict'"

I know the result will be boolian as"TRUE/FALSE".

```
#dumping/saving the model
import pickle
pickle.dump(pred, open('pred.pkl','wb'))

#calling the model
predx = pickle.load(open('pred.pkl','rb'))

#testing with user data
print(predx.predict([[1,20]]))
```

[image: error message]

How can I solve the issue and fined the boolian output?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect here.  `pred` is a boolean.  You can see that it has the value False.  You pickle it to a file, then unpickle it to `predx`, which is ALSO a boolean with the value `False`.  What did you think you were pickling?  I don't see a model anywhere here.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to put those four lines into a function, which accepts two parameters and returns a boolean.

Comment: @TimRoberts, thats exactly what I want.Thanks a lot.

Comment: In fact I like to put 5 lines into a function,which accepts two parameters ( movie rating and budget) and return a Boolean after comparing the last line( pred = post_pos>post_neg).

Comment: It looks like you have four pieces of state here: multivariate_normal_pos, multivariate_normal_neg, prior_pos, and prior_neg.  Your prediction functions needs all four.  You could, I suppose, put those into a class and pickle the class object.